# Store the message deleted in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to create an **iPhone app** that will take a backup of my message(when I delete any message) on my server using web service. Is it possible to identify when user delete some message and to get that message?

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem possible unless jailbroken

Answer (score 2):

No you can't no access the messages.

All apps are sandboxed and you can't access data from other apps.